# Parse Password reset function

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6.1

I am trying to use the password reset for parse in my ios app and I can't seem to find any tutorial on the best method in swift on how to implement this into a button action but find nothing.

Anyone know a great place to look?
This is what I have so far

```
@IBAction func resetPassword(sender: AnyObject) {

    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:
        self.loginEmail.text
        block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
        [APP.hud hide:YES];
        if (!succeeded)
        {
        NSString *msg = @"Could not connect. Try again later.";
        [UIAlertView ok:msg];
        return;
        }

        [UIAlertView minimalistMessageFor:3.0
        title:nil
        message:@"Your password has been sent to your email address."
        then:^{ }];
        [self begin];
        }];

}
```

I get a Expected expression in container literal error on this one on the PFUser line.

Comment: this code is written in Objective-C, "just" translate it to swift

Comment: Wait... Your code's in both swift and obj-c... Why is that? Do you just need to translate the Obj-C code into swift? Is that the issue?

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie but Swift is what I am learning and been writing in.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following in the app I'm working on, which pop ups a alert box to enter your email and confirms the result in a new alert box:

```
@IBAction func resetPasswordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let titlePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Reset password",
        message: "Enter the email you registered with:",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var titleTextField: UITextField?
    titlePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        titleTextField = textField
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
    }

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    titlePrompt.addAction(cancelAction)

    titlePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset", style: .Destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            if let textField = titleTextField {
                self.resetPassword(textField.text)
            }
    }))

    self.presentViewController(titlePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func resetPassword(email : String){

    // convert the email string to lower case
    let emailToLowerCase = email.lowercaseString
    // remove any whitespaces before and after the email address
    let emailClean = emailToLowerCase.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())

    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(emailClean) { (success, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let success = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Success! Check your email!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            success.addAction(okButton)
            self.presentViewController(success, animated: false, completion: nil)

        }else {
            let errormessage = error!.userInfo!["error"] as! NSString
            let error = UIAlertController(title: "Cannot complete request", message: errormessage as String, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            error.addAction(okButton)
            self.presentViewController(error, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

It's also smart to convert the email users register with to lowercase before you sync it with parse in a similar way as I show with the reset method.

If you want to put in a activity indicator, so that users see that the app is busy in between the actions, create the following two methods and call Pause() in the Reset action and Restore() just before or after the if/else in the resetPassword method. Also include the following class variable: 
`var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()`

```
func pause(){
    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}

func restore(){
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
}
```

Comment: This helped me on a project I'm working on with parse. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing up swift with objective-c. I'm assuming that you are in a swift class. Try the following:

```
@IBAction func resetPassword(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground(self.loginEmail.text)

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Your password has been sent to your email address.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, the problem is that the doc is apparently not updated on that

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("email@example.com")
```

The following thing worked for me

```
PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("email@example.com", nil)
```

Hope that this will help

Comment: Guess the updated answer should be:

PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground("email@example.com", block: nil)